# Android Studio why CardView is not working?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting error "Android resource linking failed"

AAPT: error: attribute CardElevation not found.
Dependencies:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.financemanager"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
   
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.1'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

and xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:CardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
      ...

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

What I need to do? I tried some solutions from StackOverflow but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried adding `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`?

Comment: you haven't use XMLnamespace for card view

Comment: Because you have a typo. It should be ``cardElevation`` not ``CardElevation``. This line ``app:CardElevation="5dp"``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get where your issue is. You are facing issue in `CardElevation`. It is actually capital and small letter problem on `cardElevation`. You wrote `CardElevation` But, you have to write `cardElevation` instead of `CardElevation`. Make `c` small letter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
      ...

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. I spent 4-5 hours to resolve this problem.... And that was a typo

Answer (score 0):

`app:cardElevation` will solve the problem, also tried this on my device :)

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
    ...

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

also works with namespace `xmlns:card_view`

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
    ...

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can add XMLnamespace

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ... >
    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add a little explanation with your answer. :)

Comment: havent use xmlns for card view